# Folium TimeSliderChoropleth with tooltip?

Tags: python-3, choropleth, folium

I have followed an online example of using Folium to create a choropleth map with a timeslider, similar to what Aoife Currano has done in this magnificent [post](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/interactive-maps-python-covid-19-spread/) on mapping the spread of COVID back in the height of the pandemic.

To me, an obvious enhancement to this map would be adding a tooltip showing the cases of each country for each time period, such that a user can see *exactly* how many confirmed cases are recorded for each country at the given time period simply by hovering over that country.

I have searched the Folium documentation, but unfortunately, it does not appear possible to add a tooltip to this kind of map. At least, there's [no tooltip argument listed in the documentation.](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.TimeSliderChoropleth)

Is there another way of adding a dynamic tooltip to this kind of map? Or would I be better off with another library outside of Folium to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for a solution. But here is a plugin I wrote expanding upon TimeSliderChoropleth. It has tooltips and much more.

https://github.com/germaniuss/folium-timesliderchoropleth

You essentially use it like a GeoJson object in folium, however, the style_function, highlight_function, and tooltips now should point to dictionaries of timestamps.

As an example:

```py
style_function = lambda x: (
    {timestamp0: {'color':...}, ...} if x['id'] == 0
    else {timestamp0: {...}}
)
tooltips = {timestamp1: [Tooltip("Hello World!"), sticky=False), "Plain String"]}

TimeSliderChoroPleth(data, timestamps, style_function=style_function, tooltips=tooltips)
```

The tooltips variable points to a dictionary that contains entries of (timestamp, list(object)) where the list contains the style for each feature. The style_function returns a dictionary that contains entries of (timestamp, style) given a feature.

A nice way of creating the style function in case you want to use the function with the feature id is to do the following:

```
# add each feature to style dict
for feature in features:
    # you can skip a timestamp if you want (it will not be displayed)
    styledict[timestamp].append({'color': color, 'opacity': opacity})
# transpose style dict
styledict = [dict(zip(styledict, col)) for col in zip(*styledict.values())]

style_function = lambda x: stylefunction[x['id']]
timestamps = list(styledict[0].keys())
```